# Returning word from string which ends in specific suffix

Tags: sql-server

I need to return a word in a column which ends in a specific suffix in SQL Server (2014)

In this case "CV"

Example: Washer T1 11CV Gold EA
Desired outcome from substring: 11CV

I know I will have to use something like this involving Substrings and Charindexes.

This is what I have so far:

```
   SUBSTRING(PartDescription, 1 ,CHARINDEX('CV', PartDescription)+1)  AS [CV]
```

But it only returns the string up until the suffix I want.
Example: "Washer T1 11CV"

Ideally I just want to return the word in question.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is iffy, but maybe?...

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Washer T1 11CV Gold EA'


SELECT REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
     REVERSE(
     SUBSTRING(@String,1,CHARINDEX('CV', @String)+1))
    ,1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@String,1,CHARINDEX('CV', @String)+1))))) AS [CV]
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. I just added a LTRIM to get ride of the extra space. Cheers